# On/Under A Quarter/Semester system

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, usage

I have a question about the usage of the prepositions "*on*" and "*under*".  Let's say the context is colleges with semester systems and quarter systems.  From this [website](https://www.cpp.edu/~semester/faqs/background.shtml):

> Of the 48 contiguous states, 40 state systems (83%) operate ***on a semester system*** and 5 state systems (10%) operate ***on a quarter system***.

, which suggests that "***on*** *a quarter/semester system*" is standard English, and that "***under*** *a quarter/semester system*" is not.

But then, I saw this example sentence for the definition of "*system*" in some [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/system):

> def 3a:  ***Under*** the new system, students will have to pass an exam to graduate.

So, which one of "***on*** *a quarter/semester system*" or "***under*** *a quarter/semester system*" is standard English?

Comment: Why would you presume that one sentence from one website that isn't about English grammar would imply that something is or is not standard English? Why do you think that "operate on X" should the same as "Under x"?

Comment: RE: _...which suggests that "on a quarter/semester system" is standard English, and that "under a quarter/semester system" is not._ **Absolutely not**. The use of the preposition _on_ may suggest that _on_ could be correct, but it says nothing about the suitability of _under_.

Answer (score 2):

They both are correct, and they are expressing two different situations.

The semester example is about condition of operation and happens to be about time

> **On** a semester system
>   **On** a set schedule
>   **On** Mondays, Wednesdays, and Fridays

In the second example, it is about being in a subordinate condition

> **Under** the new system
>   **Under** the current laws
>   **Under** the watchful eye of the instructor

students, people, and trainees are subordinate in these cases.

> The school runs **on** a semester system, and students are still required to attend class **under** the semester system.